# AdMob: How long does it take to display ads?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I would like to know how long does it take AdMob to display ads in your new app with ads. I just added AdMob to my app and added the app to the AddMob site and got the publisher ID. I have other apps in AdMob as well, which I published months ago. While all of my previous apps display ads, this new one doesn't display anything! The app "Status' of the AdMob site is also RED, which stands for "Inactive: AdMob has never received an ad request for your site".

I tried adding publisher ids of my other apps into this app so I can "trick" the AdMob, but that also didn't work.

How long does it take a new app to get adds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ad should be displayed with in seconds, You should check the Logcat, the admob library will point out what its problem.

I guess you don't have enough space for the Ad, of the key is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I getting ads according to the LogCat. Enough space also there. Key is also correct.

Comment: AWESOME! I HAD TO REMOVE THE PADDING! THANKS!